# Jest with typescript not allowing to import default exports directly

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a React application written using Typescript. Below the is the tsconfig i use in my project. I am able to import the defaults properly without any issues. All my files have `import React from 'react'`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "types": ["jest"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "protractor": ["integration-tests/protractor.d.ts"]
    },
  },
  "exclude": [".yarn", "**/node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["**/*.js", "**/*.jsx", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.json"]
}
```

But when i run the unit tests using Jest, jest is complaining about the defaults. So, Jest does not like defaults and complain that it is undefined. I am using ts-jest for transforming. Is there a config that i am missing in jest for it to detect the defaults in normal es6 fashion?

To be clear, i am able to import like `import * as React from 'react'` but i want to use the standard ES6 way of importing like `import React from 'react'` not the typescript way.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Typescript will set `esModuleInterop` to be `false` which requires you import as namespace.

You would change it to be `true` to be able to import without a namespace like you want to have:

`tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Typing support for this case
  "esModuleInterop": true,
}
```

NOTE: You might have to run with option `jest --no-cache` to prevent caching as you have made your configuration.