# Imports don't work properly from Jest with ts-jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using Jest with ts-jest to test TypeScript code.

Everything works except when importing libraries. They don't work if I write `import dotenv from 'dotenv';` but if I use this style `import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';` then everything works. Although I could change my code to match this style, I would prefer to fix this issue.

This is my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: { '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest' },
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: '/tests/.*\\.(test|spec)?\\.(ts|tsx)$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@apps/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/apps/$1',
    '^@core/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/core/$1',
  },
};
```

And this my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "Node16",
    "paths": {
      "@apps/*": ["./src/apps/*"],
      "@core/*": ["./src/core/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "target": "ES2021"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "tests/**/*", "index.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest with typescript not allowing to import default exports directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922694/jest-with-typescript-not-allowing-to-import-default-exports-directly)

Answer (score 0):

The question [was already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64933136/2718862).

My `tsconfig.json` needed this option: `"esModuleInterop": true`.